# Exclusive or types in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to make a typescript function that takes an argument that matches one of two conditions:

```
type A = {
  x: string
}

type B = {
 y: string
}

function testFunc(param: A | B) {
  ...
}
```

however typescript lets me call the function with both keys:

```
testFunc({x: "x", y: "y"})
```

Shouldn't the union type make it so that this function requires A ***or*** B?

Playground demonstrating the issue [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=23&pln=10&pc=32#code/FAFwngDgpgBA8gO1gXhgb2DLMAeAuGAZxACcBLBAc2AF9hRJYAVAdwHsZUNsYwDjyVWvQBmAVwQBjEGTYIYIKMQAUEEmwiECyxLAA+MVmwCUx9JmyS5hNgBsoAOlttKq9ZuPDQSkMu7Z8GAByAEMggBoLLD5gkSDaYyA)

Comment: I think it might be interesting: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with function overloads:

```
type One = {
    x: string
}

type Two = {
    y: string
}


function test(props: One): void;
function test(props: Two): void;
function test(props: (One | Two)) {
    console.log(props)
}

test({
    x: 'a',
}) // ok

test({
    y: 'f'
}) // ok
test({
    x: 'a',
    y: 'f'
}) // error
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBA8gO1gXhgb2DLMAeAuGAZxACcBLBAc2AF9hRJYAVAdwHsZUNsYwDjyVWvQBmAVwQBjEGTYIYIKMQAUEEmwiECiKAEoCANzZkAJgG5g4qTLkKlIVes0FWbfTCOmLV6bPmKVNQ0tGGUdGAAfGFddXXRMbEk5QjYAGygAOlS2Skdg3WFQe2VubHwYAHIAQwqAGlo4gHpGmDYAa3oAh1KsPkqRCoaYZtaOrpKErHLqusneAgqBoZGoEnUSIA)